# Error installing RMySQL to run in Docker on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, r, docker

I am trying to run MySQL in an R script running inside a Docker (actually Rocker) container, but am getting an error on the “install_packages(…” step.  The only solution I found that was somewhat similar was specific to running RedHat Linux (I am running Mac OS X 10.15) and the solution included pointing to several directories that I do not have. Running under RStudio or from the command line, RMySQL loads without a problem.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:latest
  
RUN mkdir /home/analysis

COPY install_packages.R /home/analysis/install_packages.R
COPY script_basic.R /home/analysis/script_basic.R

RUN Rscript /home/analysis/install_packages.R

CMD Rscript /home/analysis/script_basic.R
```

R files:

script_basic.R

```
library( RMySQL )
```

install_packages.R

```
install_packages(“RMySQL”)
```

Commands and responses:

```
$ docker build -t myapp .

…
Successfully tagged myapp:latest

$ docker run -it --rm myapp
Loading required package: DBI
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RMySQL’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RMySQL/libs/RMySQL.so':
  libmysqlclient.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Execution halted
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `rocker/r-dev` does not include the libraries you need to get this to run. Untested, but try something like this.

Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:latest
  
RUN mkdir /home/analysis

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libmariadbclient-dev

COPY install_packages.R /home/analysis/install_packages.R
COPY script_basic.R /home/analysis/script_basic.R

RUN Rscript /home/analysis/install_packages.R

CMD Rscript /home/analysis/script_basic.R
```

You can find the *need* for certain libraries on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html, as

```
SystemRequirements:     libmariadb-client-dev | libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev | libmysqlclient-dev (deb), mariadb-devel (rpm), mariadb | mysql-connector-c (brew), mysql56_dev (csw)
```

and a note on how to install them in `RMySQL`'s github `README.md`'s [Installation](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL#installation) section.

(The CRAN page references `libmysqlclient-dev`, but the github page suggests *"the mariadb implementation is much better"*. I don't know the premise of the statement, just explaining why I suggested one and CRAN listed another.)

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans. What you said makes sense, but adding that line gave me the same error as before. The output during "build" made it clear that a large number of "lib*" files were being loaded, but the end result was the same.

Comment: Well, despite the fact that the github page recommends `libmariaclient-dev`, perhaps try it instead with `libmysqlclient-dev` instead and see if it works.

Comment: That worked!? Ran without a problem. I'm a little stunned, but for the future, add the following line to the Dockerfile: RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libmysqlclient-dev